# count cycles in network

Tags: r, social-networking, graph-theory, igraph

What is the best way, or are there any ways implemented in are to count both 3 and 4 cycles in networks.

3 cycles equal connected groups of three nodes(triangles) to be calculated from one mode networks
4 cycles equal connected groups of four nodes(squares) to be calculated from two mode networks

If i have networks like this:

```
onemode <- read.table(text= "start end
                              1    2
                              1    3
                              4    5
                              4    6
                              5    6",header=TRUE)

twomode <- read.table(text= "typa typev
                              aa    a
                              bb    b
                              bb    a
                              aa    b",header=TRUE)
```

I thought

```
 library(igraph)
 g <- graph.data.frame(twomode)
 E(g)
 graph.motifs(g, size = 4)
```

would count the number of squares in my two mode network but I dont understand the output. I thought the result would be 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?graph.motifs`

> graph.motifs searches a graph for motifs of a given size and returns a
>   numeric vector containing the number of different motifs. The order of
>   the motifs is defined by their isomorphism class, see graph.isoclass.

So the output of this is numeric vector where each value is the count of a certain motif(with sizes is 4 or 3) in your graph.

```
 graph.motifs(g,size=4)
```

To get the total number of the motifs, you can use `graph.motifs.no`

```
graph.motifs.no(g,size=4)
[1] 1
```

Which is the number of the motif 20

```
which(graph.motifs(g,size=4) >0)
[1] 20
```

Comment: Which is the number of the motif 20 ?

Comment: I tried to get it in `?graph.isoclass` but the help is not really helpful..try to get it by examples..draw multi graphes(using the build-in graphs) then test graph.motifs..

Answer (score 0):

Another function that might be easier to use for this taks is kcycle.census {sna}. Details: http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/sna/html/path.census.html